# Creating an image for ImageList on the fly in case image file is missing from disk

Tags: vb.net

I have an ListView in which I load images
but in case I don't find the image on disk I want to create one on the fly and add it to the list like in the pseudo code from the Else brach.
Do you know how I would go about doing this?

```
If IO.File.Exists(fileName) Then
        Dim myImage As System.Drawing.Image = Image.FromFile(fileName)
        ImageList1.Images.Add(myImage)
Else
        ' Dim blackImage= create a black image 
        ' ImageList1.Images.Add(blackImage)

End If
```

Comment: One way is to include a default or error image and store it in Resources

Comment: @Plutonix I'll check that, sounds better than a black image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  Dim flag As New Bitmap(200, 100)
        Dim flagGraphics As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(flag)
        Dim Black As Integer = 0
        Dim BBuffer As Integer = 10
        While BBuffer <= 100
            flagGraphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Black, 0, Black, 200, 10)
            flagGraphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Black, 0, BBuffer, 200, 10)
            Black += 20
            BBuffer += 20
        End While
        ImageList1.Images.Add(flag)
```